# Creating line items in Ubercart 3

Tags: ubercart

I have to build a module to add custom charges along with the order, e.g., gift wrapping charges.

I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: Questions about tutorials are not so much helpful, as the answers just contain a link to a tutorial. It is much preferable a question where the users can show code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done exactly this before; I'll dump the code I used. Hopefully, it'll give you an idea.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function uc_giftwrap_menu() {
  $items['admin/store/settings/giftwrap'] = array(
    'title' => 'Gift Wrapping',
    'access arguments' => array('administer gift wrap'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('uc_giftwrap_admin_form')
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_permission().
 */
function uc_giftwrap_permission() {
  return array(
    'administer gift wrap' => array(
      'title' => 'Administer Gift Wrap Settings'
    )
  );
}

/**
 * Form builder for the gift wrap settings.
 */
function uc_giftwrap_admin_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['uc_giftwrap_cost'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Gift Wrap Cost'),
    '#description' => t('Total cost of gift wrapping for an order.'),
    '#default_value' => round(variable_get('uc_giftwrap_cost', '0.00'), 2),
    '#field_prefix' => '&pound;',
    '#size' => 10
  );

  return system_settings_form($form);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_uc_checkout_pane().
 */
function uc_giftwrap_uc_checkout_pane() {
  $panes['gift_wrap'] = array(
    'callback' => 'uc_giftwrap_uc_checkout_pane_callback',
    'title' => 'Gift Wrapping',
    'desc' => 'Provide gift wrapping options for the checkout.',
    'weight' => 5
  );

  return $panes;
}

/**
 * Callback for the checkout pane.
 */
function uc_giftwrap_uc_checkout_pane_callback($op, $order, $form = NULL, &$form_state = NULL) {
  if ($op == 'view') {
    $description = t('Please check this box if you wish your order to be gift wrapped.');

    $contents['gift_wrap'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('Add Gift Wrapping') . ' (' . uc_currency_format(variable_get('uc_giftwrap_cost', 0)) . ')',
      '#default_value' => isset($_SESSION['uc_giftwrap_checkout']) ? 1 : 0,
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'uc_giftwrap_update_line_items',
        'effect' => 'slide'
      )
    );

    return array('description' => $description, 'contents' => $contents);
  }
  else if ($op == 'process') {
    if ($form_state['values']['panes']['gift_wrap']['gift_wrap'] == 1) {
      if (!isset($_SESSION['uc_giftwrap_checkout'])) {
        uc_order_line_item_add($order->order_id, 'gift_wrap', 'Gift Wrapping', variable_get('uc_giftwrap_cost', 0));
        $id = db_query('SELECT MAX(line_item_id) FROM {uc_order_line_items}')->fetchField();
        $_SESSION['uc_giftwrap_checkout'] = $id;
      }
    }
    else {
      if (isset($_SESSION['uc_giftwrap_checkout'])) {
        uc_order_delete_line_item($_SESSION['uc_giftwrap_checkout']);
        unset($_SESSION['uc_giftwrap_checkout']);
      }
    }
  }
}

/**
 * AJAX callback for the checkout form (allows instant updating of total when gift wrap option is chosen).
 */
function uc_giftwrap_update_line_items($form, $form_state) {
  $commands = array();
  if (isset($form['panes']['payment']['line_items'])) {
    $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#line-items-div', drupal_render($form['panes']['payment']['line_items']));
    $commands[] = ajax_command_prepend('#line-items-div', theme('status_messages'));
  }

  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_uc_line_item().
 */
function uc_giftwrap_uc_line_item() {
  $items[] = array(
    'id' => 'gift_wrap',
    'title' => t('Gift Wrapping'),
    'weight' => 2,
    'default' => FALSE,
    'stored' => TRUE,
    'add_list' => TRUE,
    'calculated' => TRUE,
    'callback' => 'uc_giftwrap_uc_line_item_gift_wrap',
    'display_only' => FALSE
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Callback for line item type.
 */
function uc_giftwrap_uc_line_item_gift_wrap($op, $arg1) {
  // Required callback for hook_uc_line_item()
}

/**
 * Implements hook_uc_checkout_complete().
 */
function uc_giftwrap_uc_checkout_complete($order, $account) {
  if (isset($_SESSION['uc_giftwrap_checkout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['uc_giftwrap_checkout']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Let me try this code! I'll let you know of the outcome

Comment: Followed ur code. Successfully added permissions, admin form, checkout pane but the line item doesn't add to the order. Also the following callback function misses the definition: uc_giftwrap_uc_line_item_gift_wrap

Comment: @kiamlaluno: please see the comment above.

Comment: @MuhammadAnasKhan Uh? `:)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno, sorry I am newbie in module development. Infact, this is my first one!

Comment: If you please help then I would be able to meet the project deadlines.

Comment: @MuhammadAnasKhan I'm not sure what you mean by the "callback function misses the definition"?

Comment: @MuhammadAnasKhan That is fine. I don't anything wrong in the code, anyway. The function you are referring contains a comment at the beginning; if you mean you don't understand what that function's purpose is, Clive can expand on that.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, the function body only contains a comment. I think it should contain some code to add the line item to the order. Plz correct me if am wrong.

Comment: @MuhammadAnasKhan I get the function is required from Ubercart, but the function is empty because there is no code to be executed from that function, which still needs to be present because Ubercart would report an error, or would not work correctly. That is at least what I get, as the code is supposed to be complete. (See the phrase at the beginning, "I've done exactly this before.")

Comment: What @kiamlaluno said is spot on...the callback is required by Ubercart but doesn't actually need to run any code in this instance.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, Okay for the function, however I don't see the gift-wrapping charges neither on the Review Order page nor on the "My Order" block on the right hand side. Is there any other hook which I'll need to implement to add gift-wrapping charges to the order block

Comment: This module worked for me right out of the box. Thank you! This should be an officially-released module.

Comment: Is there a way to map a specific SKU number to this custom gift wrap item in the cart? I need that for an accounting software integration.

Comment: @Clive Is there a way to modify this code to allow a quantity selector? For example, I would like to instruct my customers to choose a quantity of two "gift box" checkout items if they have more than 8 products in their cart.