# Gift Wrap Option Ubercart 3 on Drupal 7

Tags: 7, ubercart

I would like to add a global gift wrap option to our checkout pane on Ubercart 3 (running on Drupal 7).

It is an option that can apply to any product and has a fixed price no matter how many products are purchased.

I do not want to add it as an attribute to individual products or product classes, but would like to add a simple yes/no radio button to all checkouts.  If yes is selected, the fixed amount is added to the order.

What is the simplest/best way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to create a Gift Wrap product class.    Create a node of this custom type with the price of your gift wrap option.     Then create a view of the custom Gift Wrap entity and display it prominently as a block on your cart and checkout pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using following way,

1. You can use **hook_checkout_pane**() to create your 'simple yes/no radio button' to all checkouts
2. If yes is selected, the fixed amount can be added to the order as **line_item**

A working example can find [here](http://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/ubercart-creating-line-items-tutorial), which will give you idea to proceed

Also [Creating line items in Ubercart 3](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25495/creating-line-items-in-ubercart-3) , check this similar question

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found is to install Ubercart Webform and
Ubercart Webform Checkout Pane. Create a Gift Wrap product and add it as a Form component to your form. Then under Form settings, check 'Generate a checkout pane'.